Simple Sieve of Eratosthenes
I've implemented this version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes in Rust, with inputs. I'm mostly pleased with it, but want to know if the input logic can be simplified, and if the sieve itself can be optimised.
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Enter the number to search up to: ");
    let mut num_primes = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut num_primes)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    num_primes = num_primes.trim().to_string();
    let mut twin = String::new();
    while twin != "y" && twin != "n" {
        twin = String::new();
        println!("Check for twin primes? Y/N");
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut twin)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        twin = twin.trim().to_lowercase().to_string();
    }
    let prime_count: usize = num_primes
        .replace(",", "")
        .replace("_", "")
        .parse()
        .expect("Invalid number entered!");
    let primes = sieve(prime_count);
    println!("{}", primes.len());
    if twin == "y" {
        let prime_check: HashSet<_> = primes.iter().collect();
        let twin_primes: Vec<_> = primes
            .iter()
            .filter_map(|prime| {
                if prime_check.contains(&(prime + 2)) {
                    Some((prime, prime + 2))
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
            .collect();
        println!("{}", twin_primes.len());
    }
}

fn sieve(num_primes: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut is_prime = vec![true; num_primes + 1];
    is_prime[0] = false;
    is_prime[1] = false;
    let mut current_prime = 1;
    while current_prime * current_prime <= num_primes {
        current_prime += 1;
        while !is_prime[current_prime] {
            current_prime += 1;
        }
        for factor in 2..=num_primes / current_prime {
            is_prime[current_prime * factor] = false;
        }
    }
    (0..=num_primes).filter(|i| is_prime[*i]).collect()
}


Whenever I see someone implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes, I like to direct them to this brilliant paper: The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes by Melissa E. O’Neill. In the paper, O’Neill explains why the popular Haskell example of the Sieve of Eratosthenes is not, in fact, an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, defines what the "essence" of the Sieve of Eratosthenes is and what an implementation must provide in order to call itself an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, and provides an alternative Haskell implementation

… that does fulfill those requirements. While the code is in Haskell, and the paper is sparked by a typical Haskell code example, the discussion of the question "what does it mean for a program to be an implementation of an algorithm, when is an implementation of an algorithm, genuinely an implementation of that algorithm, which criteria have to be met?" are language-agnostic. I am by no means a Rust expert, but as far as I can tell, your code does pass O'Neill's criteria and is a genuine implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Nice work!

@JörgWMittag It's a very interesting paper. However, the PDF is located in a personal directory at the Harvey Mudd College's server www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/, and I suppose it may disappear some day after M.E.O'Neill stops to be their employee. So I looked around for a while and here is the published version of the paper, hopefully more persistent: https://doi.org/10.1017/S0956796808007004 and corresponding bibliographic data for future searches: Melissa E. O’Neill The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes, Journal of Functional Programming, Volume 19, Issue 1, January 2009, pp. 95 - 106.

@CiaPan: Thanks for providing the DOI. I happen to have both the title of the paper and the author's name memorized, so I just put them into a search engine and used the first link.

Overall shape
I'm not really a rust expert, but this code looks generally fine to me. Good job running cargo fmt and cargo clippy on that snippet - it immediately shows that you care about what you build. Great, please keep going!
Missing tests
This is an algorithm which is really easy to test: at the very least by just comparing its output for several inputs to known primes.
Here's how I would start that:
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::sieve;

    #[test]
    fn test_sieve_1() {
        assert_eq!(sieve(0), vec![]);
        assert_eq!(sieve(1), vec![2]);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_sieve_2() {
        assert_eq!(sieve(2), vec![2, 3]);
        assert_eq!(sieve(10), vec![2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]);
    }
}

Uh-oh. Both tests fail - first one dies hard, second produces unexpected output. Oh well, expected... Next section:
Confusing variable name
I saw this signature:
fn sieve(num_primes: usize) -> Vec<usize>

this signature immediately says in plain text: produce a vector of first num_primes numbers. But the function isn't doing that! We don't get num_primes outputs, we get outputs up to num_primes - that parameter would be better named max_prime or something like that.
So after understanding that I can fix the test, and the second one passes now. Still, the first one dies hard...
Correctness
It's fine to say "some input is invalid", but that should be declared somehow. main function also doesn't perform any bounds checking, so I can enter 1 to get the hard crash!
Enter the number to search up to: 
1
Check for twin primes? Y/N
Y
thread 'main' panicked at src/main.rs:50:24:
index out of bounds: the len is 2 but the index is 2
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

That's not so cool. Since 0 and 1 are reasonable inputs, let's just patch sieve to return am empty vector:
fn sieve(max_prime: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    if max_prime <= 1 {
        return vec![];
    }
    // ...
}

Now we can have both tests pass.
Efficiency
I don't have anything to say about the core sieve algorithm, it looks pretty solid. However, the twins filtering doesn't need a hashmap: if primes are twins, they are also consecutive. And let's extract that to a helper, leaving main to deal with IO only.
I'd use itertools::tuple_windows to make this less painful, but also provide a stdlib version below for reference.
You decided to return a vector of twin pairs which is a sensible design. A flat Vec might be more convenient, but it depends on the actual usecase.
fn filter_twin_primes(primes: &[usize]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    use itertools::Itertools;
    primes
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .tuple_windows()
        .filter(|(first, second)| second - first == 2)
        .collect()
}

and a test:
#[test]
fn test_twins() {
    assert_eq!(
        filter_twin_primes(&vec![2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]),
        vec![(3, 5), (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19)]
    );
}

I prefer the cloned version, but you can also return references or use into_iter, but unless we're talking about huge amounts of primes this shouldn't matter, and usability is better without consuming input primes.
And here's an stdlib version:

fn filter_twin_primes(primes: &[usize]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    let mut second_iter = primes.iter().cloned();
    second_iter.next(); // Skip the first item
    primes
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .zip(second_iter)
        .filter(|(first, second)| second - first == 2)
        .collect()
}

Usability
Even when an invalid number is entered, you first ask whether to filter twins. Let's move validation a bit higher.
It's also moderately common to print short input prompts without line break,  so that the input follows the prompt on the same line.
You aren't consistent with bad input rejection: you keep asking for Y/N, but abort on wrong number. I'd suggest to die in either case, but you can also make both a loop.
Let's also follow the convention of indicating (and using) defaults for Y/n prompts: upper case represents the default, lower case - everything else.
Finally, a wrong input usually shouldn't produce a whole stack trace. That would be slightly more verbose, but IMO better from the UX perspective.
Here's how I'd structure that part myself:

fn main() {
    print!("Enter the number to search up to: ");
    io::stdout().flush().expect("Failed to print the prompt");
    let mut buf = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut buf)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    let Ok(max_prime) = buf
        .trim()
        .replace(",", "")
        .replace("_", "")
        .parse::<usize>()
    else {
        eprintln!("Please enter a non-negative number.");
        return;
    };

    print!("Check for twin primes? [Y/n] ");
    io::stdout().flush().expect("Failed to print the prompt");
    let mut buf = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut buf)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    let should_filter_twins = match buf.trim().to_lowercase().as_str() {
        "y" | "yes" | "" => true,
        "n" | "no" => false,
        _ => {
            eprintln!("Please answer `yes` or `no`, or press Enter to use the default.");
            return;
        }
    };

    let primes = sieve(max_prime);
    println!("Primes count up to {}: {}", max_prime, primes.len());
    if should_filter_twins {
        let twin_primes = filter_twin_primes(&primes);
        println!(
            "Twin primes pairs count up to {}: {}",
            max_prime,
            twin_primes.len()
        );
    }
}

(the second block here probably deserves to be a function on its own: fn confirm(prompt: &str) -> bool)
